# Why is the else not a valid expression

Tags: c#

The error I'm getting from this code is that else is invalid expression term. Why is this?

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int magicnumber;
    if(int.TryParse(textBox2.Text,out magicnumber));
    {
        MessageBox.Show ("Your number is " + magicnumber);                              
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Failure");
    }
}
```

Comment: The dangling semicolon.

Answer (score 2):

You closed the `if` statement with a semicolon:

```
if(int.TryParse(textBox2.Text,out magicnumber));
```

The block below it simply declares a new scope, and will always execute. The `else` block below *that* has no matching `if` and so is an error.

Answer (score 1):

Your if statement ends with a semicolon. Just remove the semicolon from the end of the if statement and it should be working.

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int magicnumber;
        if(int.TryParse(textBox2.Text,out magicnumber))
        {
            MessageBox.Show ("Your number is " + magicnumber);                              
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Failure");
        }
    }
```